# Cython returned memoryview is always considered uninitialized

Tags: python, numpy, cython, memoryview

Similar to [Cython Memoryview as return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974003/cython-memoryview-as-return-value), but I didn't see a solution other than hacking the generated C code.

I'm using Cython 3.0, but it looks like the result is the same with `<3`.

Here's an example:

```
# cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, cdivision=True, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, nonecheck=False
cimport cython
from cython cimport floating
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()

def test_func():
    cdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=2] arr = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=np.float32)
    cdef float[:, ::1] arr_view = arr
    _run(arr_view)

cdef void _run(floating[:, ::1] arr_view) noexcept nogil:
    cdef floating[:, :] tmp = _get_upper_left_corner(arr_view)

cdef inline floating[:, :] _get_upper_left_corner(floating[:, ::1] arr) noexcept nogil:
    return arr[:-1, :-1]
```

Then run `cython -a cython_test.pyx` and it shows that the `_get_upper_left_corner` function has memoryview initialization code including a GIL acquire and the `_run` function has error checking because the `_get_upper_left_corner` function could return an error (at least that's my guess):

```
+17: cdef inline floating[:, :] _get_upper_left_corner(floating[:, ::1] arr) noexcept nogil:

static CYTHON_INLINE __Pyx_memviewslice __pyx_fuse_0__pyx_f_11cython_test__get_upper_left_corner(__Pyx_memviewslice __pyx_v_arr) {
  __Pyx_memviewslice __pyx_r = { 0, 0, { 0 }, { 0 }, { 0 } };
/* … */
  /* function exit code */
  __pyx_L1_error:;
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __pyx_gilstate_save = __Pyx_PyGILState_Ensure();
  #endif
  __PYX_XCLEAR_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_t_1, 1);
  __pyx_r.data = NULL;
  __pyx_r.memview = NULL;
  __Pyx_AddTraceback("cython_test._get_upper_left_corner", __pyx_clineno, __pyx_lineno, __pyx_filename);
  goto __pyx_L2;
  __pyx_L0:;
  if (unlikely(!__pyx_r.memview)) {
    #ifdef WITH_THREAD
    PyGILState_STATE __pyx_gilstate_save = __Pyx_PyGILState_Ensure();
    #endif
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Memoryview return value is not initialized");
    #ifdef WITH_THREAD
    __Pyx_PyGILState_Release(__pyx_gilstate_save);
    #endif
  }
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __Pyx_PyGILState_Release(__pyx_gilstate_save);
  #endif
  __pyx_L2:;
  return __pyx_r;
}
```

I would have assumed the slicing on the memoryview would have created a new struct. I can live with the struct being initialized if it has to be, but I really don't want the GIL to be acquired. Is there any way of accomplishing a returned memoryview without the GIL? If I need to initialize something, how can I do that without copying the potentially large numpy array (I'm only reading it).

**Edit**: I made the example even smaller:

```
# cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, cdivision=True, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, nonecheck=False

cdef float[:] get_upper_left_corner(float[:] arr) noexcept nogil:
    return arr[:2]
```

**Edit 2**: I noticed that in my original code case, the caller (`_run` in this case) always includes a GIL acquire at the end even in the success case:

```
  /* function exit code */
  goto __pyx_L0;
  __pyx_L1_error:;
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __pyx_gilstate_save = __Pyx_PyGILState_Ensure();
  #endif
  __PYX_XCLEAR_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_t_1, 1);
  __Pyx_WriteUnraisable("cython_test._run", __pyx_clineno, __pyx_lineno, __pyx_filename, 1, 0);
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __Pyx_PyGILState_Release(__pyx_gilstate_save);
  #endif
  __pyx_L0:;
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __pyx_gilstate_save = __Pyx_PyGILState_Ensure();
  #endif
  __PYX_XCLEAR_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_v_tmp, 1);
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __Pyx_PyGILState_Release(__pyx_gilstate_save);
  #endif
```

Comment: Why did you deactivate Cython's negative index handling, when you're trying to use negative indexing?

Comment: Good point. Even changing it to `arr[:arr.shape[0] - 1, :arr.shape[1] - 1]` doesn't change this error.

Comment: To sanity check I also removed the `floating` fused type usage and just did `float` for everything. Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can live with the struct being initialized if it has to be, but I really don't want the GIL to be acquired

The GIL is only acquired on the error path (i.e. if you attempt to take an invalid slice). If you look at the generated C code you'll see that all the times the GIL is acquired are guarded by:

```
if (unlikely(!__pyx_r.memview))
```

or just after the label

```
  __pyx_L1_error:;
```

**Successfully slicing a memoryview does not use the GIL.**

Slicing a memoryview has one bit of reference counting. This is atomic, so doesn't require the GIL, but it isn't ultra-cheap. So it's probably still a good idea not to put this in your inner loop.

---

Some details that probably should have gone in the original answer:

The bits of memoryview access that are *really* optimized is access to individual array elements rather than slicing. The actual slicing is done with a utility code function `__pyx_memoryview_slice_memviewslice` which doesn't actually depend on the what Cython directives you've set.

It doesn't look like the C code is actually any different with/without the `boundscheck`/`wraparound` directives set. Some of that makes sense when you think about it - the main purpose of boundscheck is to avoid looking up the memoryview size, but here you can't avoid it since it needs to set the size of the result memoryview.

---

About the `_run`:

```
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __pyx_gilstate_save = __Pyx_PyGILState_Ensure();
  #endif
  __PYX_XCLEAR_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_v_tmp, 1);
  #ifdef WITH_THREAD
  __Pyx_PyGILState_Release(__pyx_gilstate_save);
  #endif
```

That could be improved I think since it probably is unnecessary. Note that `__PYX_XCLEAR_MEMVIEW` *may* acquire the GIL itself, but only when deallocating the final reference to the memoryview internals. The second argument (the `1`) tells it whether it needs to do that or whether it definitely has the GIL. So it isn't 100% GIL-free (although in the case of your `_run` function it won't be the final reference).

The reference counting for memoryviews has been slightly rearranged for Cython 3.0 (mainly to avoid a few corner cases where references could be leaked) so it's not completely surprising that it's changed from 0.29.x.

Edit: Resolved GitHub issue: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/5670

Comment: I don't quite agree. The if statement you pointed out is if the `memview` is null which I think means the memoryview wasn't initialized properly. The slicing and `unlikely` checking of that doesn't happen until the next line of the HTML/annotation output (the slice line). As expected (because boundscheck=False and initializedcheck=False), this does not acquire the GIL and only calls `__PYX_ERR` on failure (I think). Plus, in the function declaration code there are two GIL ensures and as far as I can tell the first always happens...but not sure how/what goto is going to `__pyx_L1_error`.

Comment: Nevermind. I read the raw C code and you're right. The annotated HTML shows the definitions in opposite order. It does do the slicing, *then* the label for the error state is specified, *then* the label for the success state which does the unlikely `memview` check and acquires the GIL. Only in the error state.

What did you mean by "Slicing a memoryview has one bit of reference counting"?

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand why these checks have to be done when I am specifically asking not to check initialization of the memoryviews.

Comment: By "Slicing a memoryview has one bit of reference counting" - somewhere in the code there will be the line with a name like `__pyx_INCREF_MEMVIEW(...)` (not sure if the exact name off the top of my head). That increments an atomic integer which ensures that the object you're viewing is kept alive as long as the memoryview exists. It isn't too expensive but it isn't free.

Comment: I think what I'm saying generally is: I think the only check that actually happens is `if (unlikely(!__pyx_r.memview))` (which is just a pointer not 0 check). That probably isn't controlled by any of the compiler directives (but I'm able to check in the next few days). It's probably a little extra work but it's not as bad as acquiring the GIL

Comment: Final point - I think the `noexcept` is probably being ignored since I'm not sure it can apply to functions returning a memoryview (or a Python object). If it isn't producing a warning for that it's probably a bug

Comment: There is no warning even if I do `cython -Wextra`. If I remove it the code looks exactly the same. I think my biggest problem with all of this is that I feel like I'm doing everything I'm supposed to be doing to avoid this type of extra code and telling cython "no, trust me, it's fine", but it is still doing the checks.

Comment: I've created a Cython bug report about not warning when `noexcept` is ignored. I've had a chance to have a closer look now, and I don't think memoryview slicing is actually affected by the compiler directives. Which is probably disappointing, but may not cost as much as you think (since it'll need a lot of the information to create the slice anyway). Anyway - the main message of the answer was supposed to be "don't panic about the GIL"

Comment: Could you take a look at my latest edit @DavidW? I'm noticing in my original use case it looks like the GIL is always acquired in the calling function to clear the memoryview, even in the success case. I can  file a bug for this if it makes sense.

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't happen in Cython 0.29.x.

Comment: I think you're right about always acquiring the GIL in the calling function - I've added a short edit about that. Probably worth reporting a bug. I don't think it'll be absolutely top priority but it could definitely be improved.

Comment: Will do and yes the second argument is 0 in the 0.29 case.